# LDAP - can't access the directory

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ldap, directoryservices

I have an ASP.NET MVC project using LDAP to authenticate users. On the development server, the authentication is working, but in production it's not working.

I had deployed the project before to production, there is no problem with the LDAP. Then I deployed again but I updated all the package in the NuGet Package Manager before the deployment. But it's not working.

Before I deployed the new project with the updated package I already tested it in development server, nothing goes wrong. It seems the problem is that I can't access the LDAP path in production server.

Here is the `<appSettings>` section:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="FolderPath" value="Files/" />
    <add key="DirectoryPath" value="LDAP://blabla.bla.bla:389/CN=Users,DC=blabla,DC=bla,DC=bla" />
    <add key="DirectoryDomain" value="bla" />
    <add key="UserPermission" value="blabla" />
</appSettings>
```

Here is the authentication code

```
public bool AuthenticateUser(string domain, string username, string password, string LdapPath, string userPermission)
{         
    string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;

    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LdapPath, domainAndUsername, password);

    try
    {
        Object obj = entry.NativeObject;

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userPermission + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

        if (null == result)
        {
            return false;
        }

        LdapPath = result.Path;
        string _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];

        if (_filterAttribute != userPermission) 
            return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
        throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
    }

    return true;
}
```

The only difference settings between development and production are the `DirectoryPath` and `UserPermission` values.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you get when you execute it?

Comment: @Anand sorry, I didn't log the error in production server. I think the problem is in DirectoryEntry, because I tried to login 3 times on the new project, then I change the project to the old one, and login again, then it works. I do that because I want to see if DirectoryEntry is passed in the new project, because if I input wrong pass 3 times in LDAP, the account will be locked so I can't login even I change the project to the new one. I hope you understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question first, are dev and production server using the same DNS?
If not, can "blabla.bla.bla" be resolved by the DNS used by production server (just try ping "blabla.bla.bla")?

If DNS cannot resolve the name then it will fail to connect.